# AS3 Saving Local File under iOS

Tags: actionscript-3, ios

I am opening and testing data using the FileStream class which is supposed to avoid file security issues. It works fine until I try to save to a local file. When I test under adl I get a security error which I though was ok (at least it was attempting to save) until the app was packaged and tested on a device, but the file fails to save. Any ideas?

```
public class FilesApp extends MovieClip {

    var file:File;
    var xmldata:XML;

    public function FilesApp() {
        // constructor code

        LoadButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,xml_load);
        ParseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,xml_parse);
        SaveButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,xml_save);
    }
    public function xml_load (e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        file = File.applicationDirectory;
        file = file.resolvePath("./Data/data.xml");

        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
        var str:String = fileStream.readMultiByte(file.size, File.systemCharset);
        fileStream.close();
        DataText.text = str;

        xmldata = XML(str);
        trace('xml file loaded');
    }
    public function xml_save (e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var writeStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        writeStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        writeStream.writeUTF("<xml><name>Changed</name><score>5000</score></xml>");
        writeStream.close();
        trace('xml file saved');
    }
    public function xml_parse (e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace('xml file saved');
        DataText.text = "Your name is:"+xmldata.name+" Your best score is:"+xmldata.score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you referring iOS as Apple iPhone/iPad's OS? I'm afraid they do not support Actionscript.

Comment: Adobe ios packager is native and was allowed by apple in september. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

Answer (score 4):

You cannot save data in `File.applicationDirectory`, it is meant to be immutable. Store it in `File.applicationStorageDirectory` instead. There is also `File.documentsDirectory` - current user documents directory, if you are sure you need to litter it with your files :)

Comment: Will give this a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Note that `File.documentsDirectory` is not a common directory on iOS, but a subdirectory of your application sandbox: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html

Comment: If you're storing large amounts of data, take a look at [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2010/01/api_tip_dont_abuse_fileapplica.html), it's best to use `File.documentsDirectory` for large files.

Answer (score 1):

For me, switching to readUTF() worked.

Also, the two lines initializing "file" should be in the constructor, else you cannot call "xml_save" (you'll have to do "xml_load" first).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try `Filereference.save()`?

Comment: Mmm... save() appears to not be a method of the fileStream class.

Comment: FileReference.Save() asks the user for a location to save.  It is not appropriate for this use.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you are using `writeUTF` to do the write and `readMultiByte` to do the read.

If you switch to `readUTF` it will work.